# Akka docker remote cluster setup

Tags: docker, client, akka, cluster-computing, remote-server

I am having issues while connecting to remote docker cluster. I did provide bind.port and bind.hostname. Still, I am having the following error on server side.

> [ERROR] [08/04/2017 12:36:34.623] [SereverApplication-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-6] [akka://SereverApplication/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2FClientApplication%4010.0.75.1%3A2553-0/endpointWriter] dropping message [class akka.actor.ActorSelectionMessage] for non-local recipient [Actor[akka.tcp://SereverApplication@127.0.0.1:2552/]] arriving at [akka.tcp://SereverApplication@127.0.0.1:2552] inbound addresses are [akka.tcp://SereverApplication@172.17.0.2:2552]

From the error I could see the messages are being sent to server actor from client. However the server child actor is unable to respond to client. Any help will be highly appreciated. I have the code at the following github location.

https://github.com/thedatatechie/akka_remote_actor

The Dockerfile is also placed at root folder. Please use it for any help in setting up the docker cluster with single node.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/RichardHightower/akka-ec2-example/wiki/Adding-docker,-and-docker-compose-support-for-our-Akka-microservice-example
This must help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error. Maybe can help you.
In the config, **remote.netty.tcp.hostname="localhost"**. However,  I use the url: akka.tcp://HelloRemoteSystem@**127.0.0.1**:5150/user/RemoteActor to connect the remote server. After correct it, error is dismiss.